# Как получить список фалов в папке, не создавая массив файлов?

Tags: java, файлы

Нашел этот код для получения списка файлов

```
import java.io.File;
...
   File myFolder = new File("c:\myfolder");
   File[] files = myFolder.listFiles();
```

Проблема тут что моя папка вероятно будет имметь громадное количество файлов. Сами JAVA объекты файлов мне не нужны. Мне просто нужно итерировать через имена файлов. Списка/массива типа `List<String>` или `String[]` будет достаочно.

Есть ли возможноть получить то что я хочу? Будет ли это значительным увеличением в производительности по сравнению с вышепреведенным кодом?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `ForEach OneFile In MyFolder.Files` чем не устраивает? Ну в синтаксисе Java, понятное дело...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

есть метод list() в java.io.File. Почитайте контракт. Кажется, вам подойдет.

А вообще это java. Она сейчас используется для создания монструозных сайтов/приложений и девелопы уже не особо заморачиваются над выигрышем в доли процента. Вы выбрали не тот язык, чтобы пытаться выиграть в мощности (речь не идет о ситуациях, где происъодят весомые утечки перфоманса)